Problem to get a product data with sp-amazon for PHp
I am building a small webapp with PHP and jlevers/selling-partner-api (https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api).
I need to recover the ASIN starting from EAN code.
I have tried this:
$catalogApi = $connector->catalogItems();


try {
    // EAN code of a product
    $ean = '3578830113254';

    $marketplaceId = 'APJ6JRA9NG5V4';
    $includedData = ["summaries", "images", "salesRanks", "productTypes", "identifiers", "variations"];

    //search EAN
    $response = $catalogApi->searchCatalogItems([
        'marketplaceIds' => [$marketplaceId],  
        'identifiersType' => 'EAN',            
        'identifiers' => [$ean],                
        'includedData' => $includedData        
    ]);

    // Visualizza la risposta
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Gestisci gli errori
    echo "Errore: ";
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}


but i receive this strange error:

SellingPartnerApi\Seller\CatalogItemsV20220401\Api::getCatalogItem():
Argument #1 ($asin) must be of type string, array given


As per Amazon searchCatalogItem API call, the identifiers parameter is:

A comma-delimited list of product identifiers to search the Amazon catalog for.

Hence you will need change your code, in order to set the identifiers as a string (not as an array of strings). In case you need to ask for more than 1 EAN, just set that parameter with a comma-separated list of EAN codes.
Warning: a maximum of 20 identifiers may be specified in the identifiers parameter.

i have try to change the code as you suggest:
    $catalogApi = $connector->catalogItems();

try {
    // EAN code of a product
    $ean = '3578830113254';

    $marketplaceId = 'APJ6JRA9NG5V4';
    $includedData = ["summaries", "images", "salesRanks", "productTypes", "identifiers", "variations"];

    //search EAN
    $response = $catalogApi->searchCatalogItems([
        'marketplaceIds' => [$marketplaceId],  
        'identifiersType' => 'EAN',            
        'identifiers' => $ean,                
        'includedData' => $includedData        
    ]);

    // Visualizza la risposta
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Gestisci gli errori
    echo "Errore: ";
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

but now the error is:
Array to string conversion, ithink that something is wrong in the API

Actually also includedData must be a comma separated string. Give it a shot. Same for marketplaceIds. I can assure that Amazon SP-API do work
